# Different fixed shipping rates for 6 different destinations

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods

I want to have the following different shipping rates for 6 different destinations. Is this possible in magento. If so, how?

Ireland & N.Ireland €3.95  (Free on orders over €50)

UK €6.00

EU €10.00

USA & Canada €12.00

Australia & New Zealand €15.00

Rest of World €20.00

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with table rates - this functionality is available out of the box. Here you can read official documentation: [How Do I Set Up Table Rate Shipping?](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping).